# Google App Engine Python Persistent Session Shared by Multiple Users

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, session-cookies, python-requests

What am I trying to do (Background info)? 
I am tasked with creating a google app engine application (Python 2.7) that posts form data to another server. The authentication for the server I am trying to connect to uses user:password in exchange for a cookie. I am able to post data to the server by passing the cookie along with the form data. I do not own the server I am posting to so no changes can be made. Every time you request a authentication cookie it invalidates the old cookie. So I am persisting the cookie/session and when it expires get a new one.

Problem I am trying to solve.
When User A is submitting the form data the cookie is still valid. (takes about 45 seconds to process all form data) 
User B is submitting the form data but the now the cookie is not valid. So by requesting a new cookie for User B, I invalidate User A cookie while their data is still being processed.

So is there a way to lock/wait all requests until the session has finished being refreshed? Or would that be a bad idea?

```
def get_session(self):
    url= self.base_url + "/index.cfm"
    form_fields = {
      "email": "user@example.com",
      "password": "passwerd",
      "iStarAPI_fuseaction": "Login"
    }
    urlfetch.set_default_fetch_deadline(60)
    #first we check the datastore if a persistent session exsists
    persistent_s = PersistentSession.query(ancestor=ndb.Key(PersistentSession,'SESSION')).fetch()
    #ok we found a session in the datastore if its not expired we are going to use that one
    if persistent_s:
        if persistent_s[0].expires_at > datetime.datetime.utcnow():
            return pickle.loads(persistent_s[0].session)
        else:
            try:
                s = requests.Session()
                s.post(url, data=form_fields)
                date_now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
                delta = datetime.timedelta(seconds=1500)
                session_expiry_time = date_now + delta
                persistent_s[0].expires_at = session_expiry_time
                persistent_s[0].session = pickle.dumps(s)
                persistent_s[0].put()
                return s
            except Exception,e:
                logging.error(e)

    #there was no session in the datastore or it was expired we need a new one
    else:
        try:
            s = requests.Session()
            s.post(url, data=form_fields)
            date_now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
            delta = datetime.timedelta(seconds=1500)
            session_expiry_time = date_now + delta
            persistent_s = PersistentSession(parent=ndb.Key(PersistentSession, 'SESSION'))
            persistent_s.expires_at = session_expiry_time
            persistent_s.session = pickle.dumps(s)
            persistent_s.put()
            #this is the important login session (all requests use the same session until it expires)
            return s
        except Exception, e:
            logging.error(e)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 'lock' can be a 'close to expiring' flag plus a counter of the active form submissions (incremented when a submission starts and decremented when it ends). The flag can be a simple check of the expiry time, but the counter needs to be in the db.

If the flag is set and the counter is non-zero then block starting new postings (for example with a while loop). Only the last active posting actually refreshes the cookie before decrementing the counter (from 1 to 0).

However locking a 'live' request for too long may cause your app instance to be killed due to exceeding the time quota (for example if those average 45 secs go occasionally above 60).

A possible solution to this would be to push the actual postings onto a task queue. If posting is locked you just need to 'fail' all task executions and GAE will automatically re-try them (for a while) - tasks should pass automatically once the cookie is refreshed and the lock is lifted. Cons: this would generate some noise in the logs due to task failures. Also very high traffic could cause exceeding the task queue limits.

Another possibility is to pre-emptively refresh the cookie after a post when it nears expiration and there are no other posts in progress/waiting. Cons: not guaranteed to work - if the flow of requests is high enough to not find such 'idle' spots before the expiration.

The only reliable way I can think of for handling locking during traffic peaks would be to use the datastore to 'buffer' the posting jobs which you would replay after the lock is lifted (again the task queue would be an easy way of triggering the replay operation).